# How to display Multiple Post Thumbnails plugin custom post thumbnail image in custom template

Tags: wordpress, image, meta-boxes

I have used wordpress **Multiple Post Thumbnails** plugin to add custom post meta box image field.

`if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
    new MultiPostThumbnails(
        array(
            'label' => 'Homepage Full-Width',
            'id' => 'homepage-full-width',
            'post_type' => 'post'
        )
    );
}`

I want to display this new featured image with full size in my site Home page big banner default featured image (http://nimb.ws/YelErQ).

Right now theme above post featured image display using following code in theme front-page.php file.

`<?php
$lead_article = ot_get_option('lead_article');
if (has_post_thumbnail($lead_article)) :
    $lead_article_img_horizontal = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($lead_article), "tol-horizontal");
    $lead_article_img_vertical = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($lead_article), "tol-vertical");
    $lead_article_img_horizontal_src = esc_url( $lead_article_img_horizontal[0]);
    $lead_article_img_vertical_src = esc_url( $lead_article_img_vertical[0]);
?>`

`<div id="lead-article" class="post featured-style10 post-header">`

`<div  data-interchange="[<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal_src ?>, landscape], [<?php echo $lead_article_img_vertical_src ?>, portrait]" class="parallax_bg skrollable skrollable-between" data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -20%, 0px);" data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 20%, 0px);" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0.382158%, 0px);background-image: url(<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal_src ?>)"></div>`

`</div>`

`<?php endif; ?>`

I have follow plugin instruction https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki but that can't work in my front-page.php file.

So any one know solutions for this then please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki#display-the-thumbnail), all you need to do is add this code to your template to display your custom thumbnail:

```
<?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) :
MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(
    get_post_type(),
    'homepage-full-width'
);
endif; ?>
```

Note that for this code to work as is you need to put it somewhere inside [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/).

**Update:**

Assuming `ot_get_option('lead_article')` returns an ID, try this:

```
<?php
$lead_article = ot_get_option('lead_article');
$lead_article_img_horizontal = null;
$lead_article_img_vertical = null;

if (
    class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails') 
    && MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail( get_post_type($lead_article), 'homepage-full-width', $lead_article )
):
    $lead_article_img_horizontal = MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url( get_post_type($lead_article), 'homepage-full-width', $lead_article );
    $lead_article_img_vertical = esc_url( wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($lead_article), "tol-vertical")[0] );
// Fallback to featured image if available
elseif ( has_post_thumbnail($lead_article) ):
    $lead_article_img_horizontal = esc_url( wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($lead_article), "tol-horizontal")[0] );
    $lead_article_img_vertical = esc_url( wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($lead_article), "tol-vertical")[0] );
endif;

if ( $lead_article_img_horizontal && $lead_article_img_vertical ):
?>
<div id="lead-article" class="post home-featured-post featured-style10 post-header">
    <div data-interchange="[<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal ?>, landscape], [<?php echo $lead_article_img_vertical ?>, portrait]" class="parallax_bg skrollable skrollable-between" data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -20%, 0px);" data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 20%, 0px);" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0.382158%, 0px);background-image: url(<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal ?>)"></div>
</div>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: I have already used above code but that not working. I want to display that new post meta_box image in my Home page full width post featured image. 

So i need to add that code in my custom php template.

Comment: Please review my php code that display post featured image as full width banner in Home page.`<div id="lead-article" class="post featured-style10 post-header"><div  data-interchange="[<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal_src ?>, landscape], [<?php echo $lead_article_img_vertical_src ?>, portrait]" class="parallax_bg skrollable skrollable-between" data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -20%, 0px);" data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 20%, 0px);" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0.382158%, 0px);background-image: url(<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal_src ?>)"></div>`

Comment: From your code, it seems you need to replace `$lead_article_img_horizontal_src` and `$lead_article_img_vertical_src` with `MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'homepage-full-width', get_the_ID() )` (see [get_post_thumbnail_url](https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki/Functions-and-Template-Tags#get_post_thumbnail_url) for more details.)

Comment: Can you please send me correct code in proper format.
`<?php
$lead_article = ot_get_option('lead_article');
if (has_post_thumbnail($lead_article)) :
 $lead_article_img_horizontal = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($lead_article), "tol-horizontal");
 $lead_article_img_vertical = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($lead_article), "tol-vertical");
 $lead_article_img_horizontal_src = esc_url( $lead_article_img_horizontal[0]);
 $lead_article_img_vertical_src = esc_url( $lead_article_img_vertical[0]);
?>`

Comment: Current display image code: `<div  data-interchange="[<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal_src ?>, landscape], [<?php echo $lead_article_img_vertical_src ?>, portrait]" class="parallax_bg skrollable skrollable-between" data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -20%, 0px);" data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 20%, 0px);" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0.382158%, 0px);background-image: url(<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal_src ?>)"></div>`

Comment: Please update your question and post the entire code. Sharing your code here in the comments makes it hard to read.

Comment: I have update my questions and code. So please review that. Thanks.

Comment: @Ketan I have updated my answer. Please review and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I have add your updated code but that also not display new image. Front end side display blank -> http://nimb.ws/25ihLU . Also review inspect element screen shot -> http://nimb.ws/Ei7yLq   In style background url display blank.  

So please review this and update me.

Thanks.

Comment: I have changed `echo $lead_article_img_horizontal_src ` to `echo $lead_article_img_horizontal` and all works good.

Comment: If MultiPostThumbnails "homepage-full-width" custom image not available then How can i display post default featured image? 

For this situation can you please help me to implement if condition for above code. 

Thanks.

Comment: @Ketan you could just fallback to the old code. See my updated answer for details. Note that for the code to work as is, the post must have both images set: `$lead_article_img_horizontal` and `$lead_article_img_vertical`.