# Multiple Post Thumbnails plugin not working with the-voux-a-comprehensive-magazine-theme front-page.php file

Tags: wordpress

I have create following one new post meta box:

```
// Big Artful Interiors Post Meta Box
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
    new MultiPostThumbnails(
        array(
            'label' => 'Big Artful Interiors',
            'id' => 'big-artful-interiors',
            'post_type' => 'post'
        )
    );
}
```

I want to display this new featured image with full size in place of my site Home page this section -> http://nimb.ws/PFxVej 1st featured image.

Right now above post featured image display using following code in theme front-page.php file.

```
<?php
    $artful_int_options = array('artful_int_1', 'artful_int_2', 'artful_int_3');
    $artful_ints = array();
    foreach ( $artful_int_options as $artful_int_option ) {
        if ( !empty( ot_get_option( $artful_int_option ) ) ) {
            $artful_ints[] = ot_get_option( $artful_int_option );
        }
    }
    if ( !empty( $artful_ints ) ) {
        $args_art_ints =  array('post__in'=>$artful_ints,'posts_per_page'=>3,'orderby'=>'post__in');
        $query_art_ints = new WP_Query($args_art_ints);
        
        if ($query_art_ints->have_posts()) {
                ?>
                <div id="artful_interiors">
                    <h2>Artful Interiors</h2>
                    <div class="subheading">By Luxury Home and Design Show</div>
                    <div class="row" data-equal=">.columns">
                        <div class="columns small-12 medium-9"> 
                            <div class="row">
                                <?php while ( $query_art_ints->have_posts() ) : $query_art_ints->the_post(); ?>
                                    <div class="small-12 large-12 columns post">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thevoux-single',array('itemprop'=>'image')); ?>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="featured-title">
                                            <?php if( has_category() ) { ?>
                                                <aside class="post-meta cf">
                                                    <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                                                </aside>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="columns medium-10"> 
                                                     <div class="post-title">
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>
                                                     </div> 
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="columns medium-2">
                                                    <figure class="post-gallery <?php do_action('thb_is_gallery'); ?>"></figure>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php break; endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row posts">
                                <?php while ( $query_art_ints->have_posts() ) : $query_art_ints->the_post(); ?>
                                    <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
                                        <?php 
                                            set_query_var( 'disable_excerpts', 'true' );
                                            set_query_var( 'disable_author', 'true' );
                                            get_template_part( 'inc/templates/loop/style6' ); 
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                        <div id="second_q_block" class="columns medium-3 small-12 q_block">
                            <div class="sidebar-inner fixed-me">
                                <?php tol_ad('front_artful_interiors') ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    } ?>
```

I have follow plugin instruction https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki but that can't work in my front-page.php file.

How to display this custom featured image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Multiple Post Thumbnails plugin custom post thumbnail image in custom template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805901/how-to-display-multiple-post-thumbnails-plugin-custom-post-thumbnail-image-in-cu)

Comment: No, that question is different. Please review this post Subject, description, code and screen shots. Thanks.

Comment: I have displayed second featured image using following code:


`<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php          add_image_size('post-secondary-image-thumbnail', full);
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'big-artful-interiors', NULL, 'post-secondary-image-thumbnail'); 
endif; 
?>
</a>`

Now all works Good. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$lead_article = ot_get_option('lead_article');
$thumb_id = MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id( 'post', 'homepage-full-width', get_the_ID() );
if ($thumb_id) :
    $lead_article_img_horizontal = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, "tol-horizontal");
    $lead_article_img_vertical = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, "tol-vertical");
    $lead_article_img_horizontal_src = esc_url( $lead_article_img_horizontal[0]);
    $lead_article_img_vertical_src = esc_url( $lead_article_img_vertical[0]);
?>

<div id="lead-article" class="post featured-style10 post-header">

<div  data-interchange="[<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal_src ?>, landscape], [<?php echo $lead_article_img_vertical_src ?>, portrait]" class="parallax_bg skrollable skrollable-between" data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -20%, 0px);" data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 20%, 0px);" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0.382158%, 0px);background-image: url(<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal_src ?>)"></div>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Above code hide the entire `#lead-article` div and directly display second section of my Home page. See this screen shot -> http://nimb.ws/9WZTYE

So please review and update me. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, what is the name of the theme you're using? Also, my answer was based on the code you provided; so, where (i.e. in which template file) did you place the code I provided via my answer?

Comment: We have used **The Voux - A Comprehensive Magazine Theme ** -> https://themeforest.net/item/the-voux-a-comprehensive-magazine-theme/11400130 and i have added code in theme front-page.php file.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full content or source code of the file *front-page.php*? I mean, before and after you added the code snippet in my answer. Use Pastebin.com.

Comment: Or can you right-click on the "*my site Home page big banner default featured image*" and choose *Inspect element* (or a similar developer tool)? I want to see/inspect its source code.

Comment: I have update the above code and also change screen shot. So please review that now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165476/discussion-between-ketan-and-sally).